# Very slow password checking on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS starting a few days ago

Tags: password, unlock

So whenever my password is entered it is taking 30-60 seconds to check it. This is happening on the unlock screen, when using sudo in the terminal and on any other graphical interface that uses a password. This only started happening 2-3 days ago. I've been using this installation on my laptop for several months now without any problems.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that, what to check, etc?

Comment: Suggest creating a new user; once you have, sign in as that user. Does the slowness persist? Please then click [edit] and add that fact to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It seems that an installation of Kerberos had gone a bit wrong and the system was trying and failing to authenticate with Kerberos every time. I've completely removed Kerberos from the system now and it is working fine.